# VBA- Copy specific cells to new added data

Tags: vba, excel

Here is the code that I am using to add data to specific columns.
I would like to be able to loop through a range in the sheet, and copy the entire border style of range of (A1:C1) to new added data.

```
Private Sub Add_Click()


Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim n As Long



n = sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.Id.Value
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.Title.Value
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.Sev.Value
```

Comment: Does this compile with Application.Rows.Count ?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, this does actually exist, it represents the active worksheet. Same as `ActiveSheet.Rows.Count`

Comment: @Pᴇʜ   thanks. Something new.

Comment: @QHarr Anyway I see no use in this. Probably this is by design so that anything that is not specified like `Rows` can default to `Application` automatically.

Comment: Is it only the border format? Also, where is your loop? You are looking for last row and then going one beyond that. Did you want to loop until last row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just copy the range

```
sh.Range("A1:C1").Copy
```

and paste formats

```
sh.Range("A" & n+1 & ":C" & n+1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Comment: @mesakon you realize this copies _all_ format, not just borders, right?

Comment: @Pᴇʜ yes I realized that, that's what I needed.

Comment: @mesakon then please edit you Q to reflect that.  As it stands, this A does not answer the Q you _actually_ asked.  If someone else searches _how to copy just border formats_ and finds this, it's, well, not useful...

Answer (score 0):

It seems the OP didn't ask for what they *actually* wanted, and was satisfied with an answer that copies *all* format, not just borders.  For the sake of future readers, here's a method that copies *just* borders.

```
Private Sub CopyBorders(rSrc As Range, rDst As Range)
    Dim BorderIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    If rSrc.Cells.Count <> rDst.Cells.Count Then Exit Sub
    For i = 1 To rSrc.Cells.Count
        For BorderIndex = 5 To 12
            ApplyBorder rSrc.Cells(i), rDst.Cells(i), BorderIndex
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub ApplyBorder(rSrc As Range, rDst As Range, BorderIndex As Long)
    Dim Bdr As Border
    Set Bdr = rSrc.Borders(BorderIndex)
    With rDst.Borders(BorderIndex)
        .LineStyle = Bdr.LineStyle
        If .LineStyle <> xlNone Then
            .Color = Bdr.Color
            .TintAndShade = Bdr.TintAndShade
            .Weight = Bdr.Weight
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Op would call it like this

```
sh.Range("A" & n + 1).Value = Me.Id.Value
sh.Range("B" & n + 1).Value = Me.Title.Value
sh.Range("C" & n + 1).Value = Me.Sev.Value

'Copy Borders
CopyBorders sh.Range("A1:C1"), sh.Range("A" & n+1 & ":C" & n+1)
```